# How do I calculate this integral:$\int_{0}^{1}\ln^2 \left| \sqrt x-\sqrt{1-x} \right|dx$?

Tags: integration, cauchy-principal-value

Is there someone who can show me how to calculate this integral :

$\int_{0}^{1}\ln^2\left|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{1-x}\right|dx$ ?

Comment: thank you , this what i meant

Comment: The one euals $ 2.745760280150567857295436585311663318658 $.

Comment: do you meant :e? but how ? i can't find a closed for of it's

Comment: @ zeraoulia rafik: No, the improper integral under under consideration does not equal $e$ up to its value calculated numerically both in Mathematica and Maple.

Comment: @user64494, I knew , but i meant your values of this integral

Comment: I would split the domain to which $x$ belongs to describe positive and negative regions. That way you can dispose of the absolute value and simply evaluate a finite sum of integrals having no absolute values.

Comment: no, should be absoluate value to be defined .

Comment: **Hint:** Let $x=\cos t$, use the angle-addition formula for $\cos t\pm\sin t$, and exploit the symmetry with regard to $\dfrac12$

Comment: @ lucian, it is a good idea to wonder that x=cost but sorry it's not a trigonometric form

Comment: @zeraouliarafik: I meant $x=\cos^2t$. $($Sorry$)$.

Comment: @Lucian i did that, and it ended up giving a result in terms of Catalan number, At which point I immediately gave up since I cannot imagine how I would obtain such a result. I am guessing some series method.

Comment: @grdgfgr: You are definitely on the right track. As [Bill Clinton](http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/?pid=54402) told us twenty years ago, *Stay the course. Stay the course. The future is yours.* :-$)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I substituted $x=\cos ^2 t$ and after some cleanup ended up with the expression

$$-2 \int^{\pi/2}_{\pi/4}\log ^2(\sqrt2 \cos u)\cos (2u)du=-2 \int_0^1 \frac{\left(b^2-1\right) \log ^2(b)}{\sqrt{2-b^2}} \, db$$

Which mathematica, in its infinite wisdom, evaluates as

$$\frac{1}{4} (4 C+2+\pi  (1+\log (2)))$$

Where C is the Catalan number.

Comment: Good idea with trig subsitution, I did think of doing that and then stopped due to double angle formulae overload. You seemed to have coped though. A link to the Catalan numbers is worthy of a +1 in my book :-)

Comment: I haven't got the slightest clue of how to extract a Catalan number from an integral. We might get an answer if the integration masterminds on the site decide to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm nowhere near a simple answer and it (I shouldn't think) will be a closed form, although I am sure we can exploit the fact that
$$\left(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{1-x} \right)\left(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{1-x} \right)=1$$
I have tried to re-write then as 
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{1}\ln^{2}|\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{1-x} |dx= -\int_{0}^{1}\ln|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{1-x} |\ln|\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{1-x} |dx
\end{equation}
I thought then use parts because simply derivatives of the $\ln \cdot$ would look like
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{d}{dx}\ln|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{1-x} | &=& \frac{1}{2}\frac{x^{-\frac{1}{2}}-(1-x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{1-x} } \\
\end{eqnarray}
But I'm getting nowhere quick, although I will keep trying. Obviously the downside to using integration by parts is that there will be integrals of the above to contend with too. I wonder even is there is a reduction formula that could be applied by conidering *closed* form iteratives of $ \int_{0}^{1} \ln^{m}f(x) dx$ from some $m > 1$.

Answer (score -2):

In order to develop the integral, you should make this steps,

1 Use logarithmic properties

$\int\ln^2 \left| \sqrt x-\sqrt{1-x} \right|dx$ = $\int\ 2ln \left| \sqrt x-\sqrt{1-x} \right|dx$ = $2\int\ln \left| \sqrt x-\sqrt{1-x} \right|dx$

2 Now I would suggest you to this variable change, x=(\sin x)^2, so our new integral, using trigonometrical identities, is,
   $4\int\ln\left|(\sin x -\cos x )\right|\ sin x\ cos x dx$

3  Here use the formula, $\int u*dv$ = $u*v - \int v*du$
where u=$\int\ln(\sin x -\cos x )$
      $dv=sin x \cos x dx$,
Then, you have to solve a trigonometrical integral, which can be easily solved by the universal change of variable

Comment: It's hard to read that. And what are sen and sn?

Comment: @lucia, it's a good for you to write this answer as a comment

Comment: I'm sorry but that's my first post, I hope it helps

Comment: Take care : $\ln^2x\neq 2\ln x=\ln \left(x^2\right)$.

Comment: Wrong._________

Comment: wrong completly